# cannot connect to cassandra on python(using cassandra-driver

Tags: python-3.x, cassandra

**Code**:

```
ap = PlainTextAuthProvider(username='cassandra',password='cassandra')
cass_contact_points=['localhost']
cluster = Cluster(['localhost'],auth_provider=ap)
session = cluster.connect('dbsi')
```

**Output:**

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/Users/rvcsp/PycharmProjects/untitled25/hotel.py", line 9, in
>   
>       session = cluster.connect('dbsi')   File "C:\Users\rvcsp\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\cassandra\cluster.py",
>   line 1270, in connect
>       self.control_connection.connect()   File "C:\Users\rvcsp\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\cassandra\cluster.py",
>   line 2773, in connect
>       self._set_new_connection(self._reconnect_internal())   File "C:\Users\rvcsp\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\cassandra\cluster.py",
>   line 2816, in _reconnect_internal
>       raise NoHostAvailable("Unable to connect to any servers", errors) cassandra.cluster.NoHostAvailable: ('Unable to connect to any
>   servers', {'::1': ConnectionRefusedError(10061, "Tried connecting to
>   [('::1', 9042, 0, 0)]. Last error: No connection could be made because
>   the target machine actively refused it"), '127.0.0.1':
>   ConnectionRefusedError(10061, "Tried connecting to [('127.0.0.1',
>   9042)]. Last error: No connection could be made because the target
>   machine actively refused it")})

Answer (score 0):

Check that:

- Cassandra is listening on the `localhost` & port 9042
- there is no firewall that prevents connection to port 9042
- that you can connect using `cqlsh -u cassandra -p cassandra localhost`